# Animate a highly nested style colour

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

The following style works as intended (irrelevant props stripped):

```
<Style TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Path>
                            <Path.Stroke>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
                            </Path.Stroke>
                        </Path>
                    </Canvas>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.GotFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Visual.Children[0].Stroke.Color"
                                    To="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowColor}"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

...but I doubt that it's the best way to do this. One ugly thing here is the `ColorAnimation` having to do a long `PropertyPath` traversal from the `PasswordBox` all the way to the stroke colour.

Is there any way to abbreviate or tidy this code? Is there any way to refactor it so that that `PropertyPath` traversal is any shorter?

Thus far I've tried moving the storyboard into `Path.Resources` (but then I couldn't refer to it from `Style.Triggers`); and putting a shared brush in `Style.Resources` and animating its colour (but then I get thread/freeze-related exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748266.aspx)

> ... only the framework element for which the style is defined can be targeted directly.

So there's no way to target named style parts.

It suggests that you dot down from the style target to the property you want to change, which is what you did. Given that, I think this is the best that you can do.

---

Result found using `Storyboard.TargetProperty` as google search term